# How to setup VirtualBox so I can access my guest system when I have no Internet

Tags: virtualbox

My host runs Windows. My guest Linux.
I always use the Bridge adapter to connect from my Windows to a system I have running in my guest VM...
Lets say I do not need to reach the Internet but want to test/work on the guest system even when I do not have a connection ...  like if I am on a plane for example.
What is the correct setup so that I can reach the guest OS from my host windows computer...
i.e. if I can ping the guest OS, I am in business!
...
I tried using the NAT but I did not set it up correctly ...
What do you recommend? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Host-only network. VB creates a virtual network with a virtual interfaces and virtual dhcp server. Make sure that, the DHCP server works fine. Follow these steps:

1. File
2. Networks
3. Host only networks

If it is empty you need to add a new network config. After that, you should able to ping your host from the guest OS or inversely.